# mattdiamond/Recorderjs upload issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have site using php frame work codigniter where I am using the mattdiamond/Recorderjs to record an audio file in blob content type then i am uploading it to the server but it is taking top much time to upload I want to minimize my uploading time. Max size of audio file is 4mb and it is taking 1 minute to 4 minutes for uploading to server.

```
$(document).on("click", "#save:not(.disabled)", function(){
Fr.voice.export(function(blob){

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file.wav', blob);
  formData.append('question_id',question_id);
  formData.append('test_id',test_id);
  formData.append('section_id',section_id);
  formData.append('sub_section_id',sub_section_id);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.example.com/pte/upload",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {


      if(response.status=="success"){
          $('#recording-status').html("Recording save successfully.");
          $('#recording-status').addClass("text-success");
          $("#nextbtn1").prop('disabled', false);
          href = $("#nextbtn").attr('href');              
          submit_question1(href);
      }
      else {
          $('#recording-status').html("An error occurred");
      }
      //$("#audio").attr("src", url);
     // $("#audio")[0].play();
     // alert("Saved In Server. See audio element's src for URL");
    }
  });
}, "blob");
restore();
```

});
});

Comment: What server? Did you write the server? What speed is your internet connection?

Comment: I am using Godday server. Minimum speed of internet connection is 1 mbps. I thing its not low speed to upload 4 mb audio file in 20 seconds.

Comment: godaddy shared hosting ultimate plan

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Recorder object you can pass `{numChannels:1}` to the constructor like this:

`var recorder = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})`

I believe in your case it should be: `Fr.voice = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})`

`numChannels` is an undocumented config option. It defaults to 2. When set to 1 it results in a mono recording thus halving the file size.

I've recently written in detail about `Recorderjs` and `numChannels` in [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/).

Comment: Where do I need to declare this before the start of my ajax?